# gcc makefile error: make: *** No rule to make target

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm trying to use GCC on a OS X to compile my project. 
I just modified Makefile.posix as follows:

```
GNU_INSTALL_ROOT := /usr/local/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-20143
GNU_VERSION := 4.8.3
GNU_PREFIX := arm-none-eabi
GDB_PORT_NUMBER := 9992

FLASH_START_ADDR = $(shell $(OBJDUMP) -h         $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out -j .text | grep .text | awk '{print $$4}')

JLINK_OPTS = -device nrf51822 -if swd -speed 4000
JLINK_GDB_OPTS = -noir
JLINK = JLinkExe $(JLINK_OPTS)
JLINKD_GDB = JLinkGDBServer $(JLINK_GDB_OPTS)


flash-jlink: flash.jlink
    $(JLINK) flash.jlink

flash.jlink:
    printf "loadbin $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin $(FLASH_START_ADDR)\nr\ng\nexit\n" > flash.jlink

erase-all: erase-all.jlink
    $(JLINK) erase-all.jlink

erase-all.jlink:
    # Write to NVMC to enable erase, do erase all, wait for completion. reset
    printf "w4 4001e504 2\nw4 4001e50c 1\nsleep 100\nr\nexit\n" > erase-all.jlink

run-debug:
    $(JLINKD_GDB) $(JLINK_OPTS) $(JLINK_GDB_OPTS) -port $(GDB_PORT_NUMBER)

.PHONY:  flash-jlink flash.jlink erase-all erase-all.jlink run-debug
```

When I try to start the server with the modified Makefile.posix :

```
make -f ble_app_hrs.Makefile run-debug
```

I got this error:

```
    Macintosh:gcc $ make -f ble_app_hrs.Makefile run-debug
    /bin/sh: - : invalid option
Usage:  /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
    /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
    --debug
    --debugger
    --dump-po-strings
    --dump-strings
    --help
    --init-file
    --login
    --noediting
    --noprofile
    --norc
    --posix
    --protected
    --rcfile
    --restricted
    --verbose
    --version
    --wordexp
Shell options:
    -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option      (invocation only)
    -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option
make: *** No rule to make target `JLinkGDBServer', needed by `run-debug'.  Stop.
```

Here the file ble_app_hrs.Makefile :

```
TARGET_CHIP := NRF51822_QFAA_CA
BOARD := BOARD_PCA10001

# application source
C_SOURCE_FILES += main.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += battery.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += led.c

C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_dis.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_bas.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_hrs.c

C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_srv_common.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_sensorsim.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += softdevice_handler.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_advdata.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_debug_assert_handler.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_error_log.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += ble_conn_params.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += app_timer.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += pstorage.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += crc16.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += device_manager_peripheral.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += app_trace.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += simple_uart.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += app_gpiote.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += app_button.c

SDK_PATH = ../../../../../

OUTPUT_FILENAME := ble_app_hrs

DEVICE_VARIANT := xxaa
#DEVICE_VARIANT := xxab

USE_SOFTDEVICE := S110
#USE_SOFTDEVICE := S210

CFLAGS := -DDEBUG_NRF_USER -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD

# we do not use heap in this app
ASMFLAGS := -D__HEAP_SIZE=0

# keep every function in separate section. This will allow linker to dump unused functions
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections

# let linker to dump unused sections
#LDFLAGS := -Wl,--gc-sections

INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/s110"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/ble"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/ble/device_manager"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/ble/ble_services"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/app_common"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/sd_common"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/sdk"

C_SOURCE_PATHS += $(SDK_PATH)Source/ble
C_SOURCE_PATHS += $(SDK_PATH)Source/ble/device_manager
C_SOURCE_PATHS += $(SDK_PATH)Source/app_common
C_SOURCE_PATHS += $(SDK_PATH)Source/sd_common

include $(SDK_PATH)Source/templates/gcc/Makefile.common
```

and here the file Makefile.common that uses Makefile.posix:

```
DEVICE := NRF51
DEVICESERIES := nrf51

SDK_INCLUDE_PATH = $(SDK_PATH)/Include/
SDK_SOURCE_PATH = $(SDK_PATH)/Source/
TEMPLATE_PATH += $(SDK_SOURCE_PATH)/templates/gcc/
OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY := _build

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)Makefile.windows
else
include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)Makefile.posix
endif

ifeq ($(LINKER_SCRIPT),)
    ifeq ($(USE_SOFTDEVICE), S110)
        LINKER_SCRIPT = gcc_$(DEVICESERIES)_s110_$(DEVICE_VARIANT).ld
        OUTPUT_FILENAME := $(OUTPUT_FILENAME)_s110_$(DEVICE_VARIANT)
    else
        ifeq ($(USE_SOFTDEVICE), S210)
            LINKER_SCRIPT = gcc_$(DEVICESERIES)_s210_$(DEVICE_VARIANT).ld
            OUTPUT_FILENAME := $(OUTPUT_FILENAME)_s210_$(DEVICE_VARIANT)
        else
            LINKER_SCRIPT = gcc_$(DEVICESERIES)_blank_$(DEVICE_VARIANT).ld
            OUTPUT_FILENAME := $(OUTPUT_FILENAME)_$(DEVICE_VARIANT)
        endif
    endif
else
# Use externally defined settings
endif

CPU := cortex-m0

# Toolchain commands
CC              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-gcc"
AS              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-as"
AR              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-ar" -r
LD              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-ld"
NM              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-nm"
OBJDUMP         := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-objdump"
OBJCOPY         := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-objcopy"

MK              := mkdir
RM              := rm -rf

OBJECT_DIRECTORY := _build
LISTING_DIRECTORY := _build

C_SOURCE_FILES += system_$(DEVICESERIES).c
ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_FILES += gcc_startup_$(DEVICESERIES).s

# Linker flags
#LDFLAGS += -L"$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/arm-none-eabi/lib/armv6-m"
#LDFLAGS += -L"$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/$(GNU_VERSION)/armv6-m"
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -Map=$(LISTING_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).map
LDFLAGS += -mcpu=$(CPU) -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -L $(TEMPLATE_PATH) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) 

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS += -mcpu=$(CPU) -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -D$(DEVICE) -D$(BOARD) -D$(TARGET_CHIP) --std=gnu99
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=soft

# Assembler flags
ASMFLAGS += -x assembler-with-cpp

INCLUDEPATHS += -I"../"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/gcc"
INCLUDEPATHS += -I"$(SDK_PATH)Include/ext_sensors"

# Sorting removes duplicates
BUILD_DIRECTORIES := $(sort $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY) $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY) $(LISTING_DIRECTORY) )

####################################################################
# Rules                                                            #
####################################################################

C_SOURCE_FILENAMES = $(notdir $(C_SOURCE_FILES) )
ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_FILENAMES = $(notdir $(ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_FILES) )

# Make a list of source paths
C_SOURCE_PATHS += ../ $(SDK_SOURCE_PATH) $(TEMPLATE_PATH) $(wildcard $(SDK_SOURCE_PATH)*/)  $(wildcard $(SDK_SOURCE_PATH)ext_sensors/*/) $(wildcard $(SDK_SOURCE_PATH)ble/*/)
ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_PATHS = ../ $(SDK_SOURCE_PATH) $(TEMPLATE_PATH) $(wildcard $(SDK_SOURCE_PATH)*/)

C_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(C_SOURCE_FILENAMES:.c=.o) )
ASSEMBLER_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_FILENAMES:.s=.o) )

# Set source lookup paths
vpath %.c $(C_SOURCE_PATHS)
vpath %.s $(ASSEMBLER_SOURCE_PATHS)

# Include automatically previously generated dependencies
-include $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(COBJS:.o=.d))

### Targets
debug:    CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g3 -O0
debug:    ASMFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g3 -O0
debug:    $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

.PHONY: release
release: clean
release:  CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG -O3
release:  ASMFLAGS += -DNDEBUG -O3
release:  $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

echostuff:
    @echo C_OBJECTS: [$(C_OBJECTS)]
    @echo C_SOURCE_FILES: [$(C_SOURCE_FILES)]
    @echo C_SOURCE_PATHS: [$(C_SOURCE_PATHS)]

## Create build directories
$(BUILD_DIRECTORIES):
    $(MK) $@

## Create objects from C source files
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.c
# Build header dependencies
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -M $< -MF "$(@:.o=.d)" -MT $@
# Do the actual compilation
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -c -o $@ $<

## Assemble .s files
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.s
    $(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -c -o $@ $<

## Link C and assembler objects to an .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out: $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES) $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASSEMBLER_OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASSEMBLER_OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES) -o $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out

## Create binary .bin file from the .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin

## Create binary .hex file from the .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

## Default build target
.PHONY: all
all: clean release

clean:
    $(RM) $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)

## Program device
.PHONY: flash
flash: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex
    nrfjprog --reset --program $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

.PHONY: reset
reset:
    nrfjprog --reset

.PHONY: erase
erase:
    nrfjprog --erase
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What did you expect? There is no goal `run-debugpwd` in your Makefile, only `run-debug`.

Comment: `make -f ble_app_hrs.Makefile` instructs make to read a makefile called `ble_app_hrs.Makefile` yet you say you edited `Makefile.posix`?  And the file you show us doesn't contain a target `run-debugpwd`

Comment: sorry, it was a copy& paste error. Edited

Comment: Still editing `Makefile.posix` and then executing `ble_app_hrs.Makefile` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TAB character in Brackets editor were replaced by 4 spaces (sp sp sp sp).
Changing to other editor (TextMate) solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

All these lines are wrong:

```
flash-jlink: flash.jlink    $(JLINK) flash.jlink

flash.jlink:    printf "loadbin $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin   $(FLASH_START_ADDR)\nr\ng\nexit\n" >flash.jlink

erase-all: erase-all.jlink  $(JLINK) erase-all.jlink

# Write to NVMC to enable erase, do erase all, wait for completion. reset
erase-all.jlink:    printf "w4 4001e504 2\nw4 4001e50c 1\nsleep 100\nr\nexit\n" > erase-all.jlink

run-debug:  $(JLINKD_GDB) $(JLINK_OPTS) $(JLINK_GDB_OPTS) -port $(GDB_PORT_NUMBER)
```

I don't know if you were just careless with your cut and paste, but there must be a newline and TAB on the next line, or a semicolon, before the command.  Like this:

```
flash-jlink: flash.jlink
        $(JLINK) flash.jlink

flash.jlink:
        printf "loadbin $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin   $(FLASH_START_ADDR)\nr\ng\nexit\n" >flash.jlink

erase-all: erase-all.jlink
      $(JLINK) erase-all.jlink

# Write to NVMC to enable erase, do erase all, wait for completion. reset
erase-all.jlink:
        printf "w4 4001e504 2\nw4 4001e50c 1\nsleep 100\nr\nexit\n" > erase-all.jlink

run-debug:
        $(JLINKD_GDB) $(JLINK_OPTS) $(JLINK_GDB_OPTS) -port $(GDB_PORT_NUMBER)
```

Comment: Hi, If I add a new line and a TAB before the command ($(JLINK) flash.jlink) I got this error: Makefile.posix:15: *** missing rule before commands.  Stop

Comment: Hm, if you're faithfully pasting exactly the makefile you're using above that cannot happen.  You're using a pretty old version of GNU make, though, that's clear.  You say you're on MacOSX; when you save this file are you using UNIX-style line endings (that is, LF characters or decimal 10 or hex 0x0a), or are you using old-fashioned Mac line endings (CR characters)?  If you run `od -a Makefile.posix | less` and look at the character encodings do you see the token `nl` where newlines should be, or do you see `cr`?  Older versions of GNU make didn't handle non-UNIX line endings properly.

Comment: I see this after the k and before the $ of the new line: cr  nl  sp  sp  sp  sp. Btw, I use Brackets for editing

Comment: I guess I should see cr  nl  ht ?

Comment: So.  First, you're saving your files in Windows format (CRNL is Windows line-ending fomrmat; it's not used in UNIX or traditional Mac systems).  I've never heard of "Brackets", but you need to find out if that editor has some kind of setting that lets you change the newline format: your format is wrong.  Newer versions of GNU make will accept different types of line endings but older versions (yours is at least 8 years old based on the message) do not.

Comment: Also, I said you need to start your line with a TAB character.  The output you're seeing shows that instead of a TAB character, you have four spaces (`sp sp sp sp`).  That's illegal syntax for a makefile.  Basically, I think your editor is totally incapable of and inappropriate for writing makefiles, at least unless there's some mode you can put it in where it's not manipulating your input (using normal line endings, not transforming TAB characters to spaces, etc.)

Comment: true ! I changed brakets editor for TextMate and it works !  Thanks !